# Javascript code isn't working with vuejs integration

Tags: laravel, vue.js

using Vuejs/Laravel .I use this simple javascript code to generate a chart in blade.

```
 <script>
  function getData(columnOrder, keyName) {
  var obj, table = $("#t4"), array = [];
  table.find('tbody tr').each(function() {
  var rows = $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + columnOrder +')');
  rows.each(function(){
    obj = {};
    obj[keyName] = $(this).text();
    array.push(obj);
  });
  });
  return array;
  }

  var categories = getData(1, 'label');
  var datas = getData(2, 'value');
  console.log(categories);
  console.log(datas);
```

It works when my html table contain html/php values. but when it's vuejs values, it's seems not recognizing data.. Here is my table with vuejs.

```
 <table class="hidden" id="t4">
 <thead>
 <tr>
   <th scope="col">a</th>
   <th scope="col">b</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <template v-for="person in personsWithAmount">
 <tr>
   <td scope="row" >@{{person.user.name}}</td>
   <td scope="row">@{{person.totalAmount}}</td>
 </tr> 
 </template>      
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Console.log still blank
Thank you in advance

Comment: I suspect your code is running before Vue does. You'd want to move your JS into the Vue component, so it only runs once the data etc. is all present and mounted.

Comment: Oh yes, u were right ! Thank you !

Comment: Cool - I've fleshed this out into an answer a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to take a peek at the [Vue lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram). In short, Vue takes a while to load and initialize, which means that JavaScript *outside* of Vue that relies on elements *created* by Vue may execute *before* those elements exist at all.

Generally, you're going to want to move any JS code that relies on Vue-created elements into the Vue app.